# How to clear input field after submitting data in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have one `mat-select` dropdown and one `input` field. When the `button` is clicked it submits data. After data is submitted I want to clear the input field but I don't want to clear the `mat-select` dropdown. How can I do that?

chat.component.html

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select User" [(ngModel)]="userObject.userid" 
      name="userid" required>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let userObj of userObj [value]="userObj.userid">
        {{userObj.username}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>  

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Type Message" [(ngModel)]="userObject.chatmessage">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="sendMessage()">
    SEND MESSAGE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `userObject.chatmessage = '';` A better way would be to just use a ReactiveForm and then call the `reset` method on it.

Comment: Where i have to put this ?

Comment: In your Component Class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're two-way data binding to `userObject.chatmessage`, just setting it to an empty string in your component will do the trick.

In your `ChatComponent` TypeScript class, just do this:

```
sendMessage() {
  // After Sending Message
  userObject.chatmessage = '';
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: If you get the value of input field with $event you can do this                                     (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value = ' ';

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and call reset()-method on the form.

You can also manually reset the form fields as suggested above by SiddAjmera.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Reactive form is the best way to do it, https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms use this link to do it
reset the input field by assigning the empty string is not the way to do that, it will going to give error in some condition

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this while using Reactive form protocols is upon your button click is to `.setValue('')`.

So instead your send message would look like this.

```js
sendMessage() {
   // Operations here prior to resetting value...
   this.userObjectField.setValue('');
}
```